# How do I configure an azure function with a ServiceBusTrigger, on my local dev machine?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I've created an azure function with a service bus trigger, using the template in VS 2022.

It looks like this:

```
public class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("Queue", Connection = "ServiceBus")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

I have a local.settings.json file

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values":
  {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBus": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
    "Queue": "QueueName"
  }
}
```

When I debug the function locally in VS I get an error:

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: Value for the connection string parameter
> name 'ServiceBusConnectionString' was not found. (Parameter
> 'connectionString').

My understanding is that the QueueName and Connection Properties of the ServiceBusTrigger attribute ("Queue" and "ServiceBus" values, respectively) correlate to the "Queue" and "ServiceBus" properties in the local.settings.json file, and the values of those properties in the json file represenent names of properties that contain the actual values of the service bus connection string and the queue name, which are stored somewhere.  But where?  I don't know where to specify those properties and values.

**Edit**
I've updated my function and configuration, based on the understanding that

```
FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("MyQueue", Connection = "ServiceBus")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log) {..}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values":
  {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBus": "ServiceBusConnectionString"
  }
}
```

I added a startup cs to add an appsettings as a configuration source:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyFunc
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Represents the startup class of the function app.
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var context = builder.GetContext();
            var config = context.Configuration; //Here you go!            
        }

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var context = builder.GetContext();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, $"appsettings.{context.EnvironmentName}.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false); 
        }
    }
}
```

I add an appsettings.json file to my project and set it to copy to output:

```
{
  "ServiceBusConnectionString": "abdef"
}
```

If I inspect the config variable in the Startup.Configure function I can see that the appsettings.json file is a config source, and I can test that configuration["ServiceBusConnectionString"] returns "abdef".

I'm still getting the error that the value for the connection string parameter name 'ServiceBusConnectionString' was not found.  I must be completely misunderstanding how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

`Queue` is the name of the queue, not a setting. So if your queue is called `orders`, you must put that in the trigger attribute, not the configuration.

`Connection` is a connection string **name**, not the connection string itself. When deployed to Azure, the value could be coming from an environmental variable, setting in the portal (Azure Functions App settings tab), or from a configuration file such as `appsettings.json` if you configure to load settings from that file.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense so far.  how do I configure it to use appsettings.json, both locally and in azure?

Comment: So I added an appsettings.json file, and set it up as a config source (see edit in my question), and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I've done that with the Isolated Worker SDK. You're using in-process SDK. In theory, that should follow the standard .NET configuration of a source. Could be a mistake in configuring the source for the configuration file. Have a look around. Something like this post [here](https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/azure-functions/dotnet/2022/05/10/use-settings-json-azure-function-en.html) outlines the steps.